# How to pass Float as Type

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to use configuration objects in my code. I have a typealias as follows:

```
typealias MyParam = Triple<String, Any, Type>
```

I then have a list of these which is populated at runtime:

```
val paramsList: MutableList<MyParam> = mutableListOf();
```

Now when I try and populate the list, I get an error:

```
paramsList.add(Triple("Strength", 0, Float))
```

It says "Type mismatch: required Type. Found Float.companion".

[image]

How can I get around this error? I will eventually need to cast a value using this `Type`.

Comment: What is `Type` here? Is it `java.lang.reflect.Type`?

Comment: What is the purpose of casting to an arbitrary type at runtime? I can’t think of a way this could achieve anything. Casting is something you do to get the compiler to let you do something with a specific type.

Comment: @Tenfour04 My application allows users to create their own interfaces. So they specify a list of attributes and it needs to create UI components (sliders, color pickers, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::class` to refer to Kotlin's `KClass` and use the `.java` property to get Java's `Class` out of it (which implements `Type`):

```kotlin
paramsList.add(Triple("Strength", 0, Float::class.java))
```

For more complex types with generics like `List<Float>`, use [`typeOf<List<Float>>()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html) which gives you the `KType` corresponding to `List<Float>`, and then [javaType](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/java-type.html) to get a `Type` out of it:

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.typeOf
import kotlin.reflect.javaType

paramsList.add(Triple("Strength", 0, typeOf<List<Float>>().javaType))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling a list with float types.If you get an error, share the error code and I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got this one figured out. By the way, I recommend asking questions, it's a better way to get your reputation up versus providing short answers like this (that probably should be comments)